# How can I use Interarchy/Filezilla etc with SSH keys?

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, filezilla

I have a server which I connect to with the command line using a stored ssh key, i.e. there's no username/password, I can just connect with `ssh servername` because the key is stored in the right place.

Is there any way to use Interarchy or another OS X GUI file client with this key?

Answer (score 1):

According to their [Wiki](http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto), it's fully supported in FileZilla.

> **Other platforms**
>
> FileZilla supports the standard SSH agents. If your SSH agent is running, the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable should be set.

EDIT:

[Check here to see alternatives for FileZilla](http://alternativeto.net/software/filezilla/?platform=mac).  I don't have a Mac, so I can't test any of these, but it's a great place to start a search.